# How to transfer windows across after changing components

Tags: windows-10

I have upgraded my CPU, mobo, ram and cooler and was wondering (using the same hard drives) if I need a new license key and what I need to do in order to use Windows after changing motherboard and CPU?

Sorry if this is not the right site. Preferably I want to be able to use my old version of windows 10 pro without paying an extra cost.

My first idea would be to install a bootable windows onto a USB drive, however, I am not sure if this is the right step or would even work.
Another point to bear in mind is that I am currently dual booting with Ubuntu.

Edit:  I have found out I am using a retail edition of Windows 10 professional.

Many thanks.

Comment: Only retail Windows 10 licenses allow you transfer the license to multiple machines. If you currently have an OEM Windows 10 license it cannot be transferee to another machine (unless you live in a region where it’s required by law)

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/980204/can-i-transfer-a-windows-10-licence-to-my-new-pc-if-it-was-upgraded-from-a-retai?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried with anything past Win7, but if a hardware failure forced a MB CPU swap, calling MS and asking (think grovel) sometimes got me a new code for the install.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of Windows license you had previously.

OEM Windows 10 "SLIC" licenses are embedded in the BIOS and stay with the motherboard forever. They can't be transferred to a new motherboard without violating Microsoft's license agreement.

Retail licenses (the kind you buy and get on a keycard) can simply be installed and activated on the new device, assuming that the key has been deactivated on the old device or Windows removed. If the key has been re-activated too many times, you may have to call Microsoft for them to allow another. If you're using the same hard drive on a different motherboard, you could technically just leave Windows alone and reactivate it once you're up and running. Having a dual-boot setup won't affect this one way or the other, as long as you can boot into Windows.

VLK and MAK keys are typically used by enterprise customers and function similarly to retail licenses, except licenses can be installed on a set number of computers. It's unlikely you have one of these types of license keys unless you're a business user.